# Mock Apache CXF JAX-WS client

Tags: java, mocking, cxf

I need to test web services in Apache CXF app, therefore, requiring some mechanism to mock a client analogous  `MockWebServiceClient` in Spring WS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple [JUnit rule project](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf) which helps with mocking the webservice. Basically you configure your client using properties to point to localhost, and mount endpoints at these locations. The endpoint servers delegate to an actual mock.

Comment: is there a way that doesn't involve the whole tcp stack?

Comment: Regular mockito?